# Using user input statements to create data tables using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is two-part question.

1) I am creating datatables based on user inputs, but is there a way to design your code so that if the user doesn't input anything, it doesn't break the script? I.E.

```
A=input('some input\n')
B=input('some input\n')
df1=pd.read_csv(A, sep='\s+', header=None)
df2=pd.read_csv(B, sep='\s+', header=None)

# This works really well if you have inputs for A and B, but if you don't have an input for B, then you get the error that B is undefined
```

What I'd like is to set up somekind of loop so if there is no input, it just skips it. I.E.

```
A=input('some input\n')
if A has some input:
    df1=pd.read_csv(A, sep='\s+', header=None)
else:

B=input('some input\n')
if B has some input:
     df2=pd.read_csv(B, sep='\s+', header=None)
else:
```

This however comes across a second issue. 
2) Later down the line, I am concating these tables (imagine I defined columns in the above datatables).

```
df3=df1.loc[:,'Column_4']
df4=df2.loc[:,'Column_4']
df5=pd.concat([df3,df4],axis=1)
```

So if in the above loop the user does not input anything for B, then you don't get the creation of df2, which means no df4. Now I can put df4 in the loop as well so I don't get the error df4 is not defined, but that would still leave an issue for the formation of df5, which I cannot put in any of the above loops.

Finally, just on the aside, is there anyway to simplify this process? Ideally I'd like to let the user put maybe 10 or 20 inputs, but it's going to be a lot of lines of code for A=input(), B=input(), C=input(), and each of those inputs with there own pd.read and .loc lines really adds up (especially if I'm creating conditional loops for every single input as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I completely understood what you're trying to accomplish but from the information in your post I'm assuming you're inputting a list of paths to CSV files that need to be processed. I came up with this script to simplify the process of getting these file paths, parsing the CSVs into dataframes into a list, taking these dataframes and extracting the "Column_4" column and then concatenating them all into one final dataframe. Just enter the CSV file paths until you're done and then enter q, quit or done and it will run with whatever file paths you provided!

```
import pandas as pd

csv_file_paths = []
data_frames = []
column_4_frames = []
path_input = ''

print('Enter path to CSV file. When done, enter q, quit or done to stop.')
# collect file paths to be processed until q, quit or done is typed and entered
while True:
    path_input = input()
    if path_input.lower() not in ['q', 'quit', 'done']:
        csv_file_paths.append(path_input)
    else:
        break

# create dataframes for each file, append them to a list
try:
    for csv_file in csv_file_paths:
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep='\s+', header=None)
        data_frames.append(df)
except Exception as e:
    # catch non-existing file error
    print('Error loading file: '+str(e))

# collect "column 4"s from each dataframe that was read
for df in data_frames:
    column_4_frames.append(df.loc[:,'Column_4'])

# concatenate all "column 4" dataframes into one
concatenated_df = pd.concat(column_4_frames, axis=1)
```

Comment: When I run this, I get the error, file b 'done' does not exist. You get this error for q and quit.

Comment: Also, what I'm trying to do is get the user to input a txt file, and then use pandas to create a datatable from that file. Then extract specific values from that datatable (Column_4), and create a new datatable from those values. However, my current setup only allows the user to input a specific amount of txt files. If they have more, they will be unable to input it, and if they have less, you will get the undefined error I had stated in my post. The setup you have now seems to be the proper way to get a user input and create a datatable from (you don't define how many inputs there should be)

Comment: Updated the code to fix that error. So are you inputting the path to the txt files or the entire txt file itself? This will work with paths to text files, however I'm not sure if it will work with direct text input or not, let me know if it runs!

Comment: The text files themselves. I plan to have another user input where they define where the files will be. E.G. A=input('Please input path to folder with files'), and then oschdir.(A), or something like that. Also, I just input the txt files themselves, and this worked beautifully. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Hope your number crunching goes well. Also you should approve my answer as the solution to your question :)

Comment: One final thing, how do you design this so if they put in the wrong filename, it'll give an error, but continue with the script. I've tried to change it so that it goes: While True: try:  'the rest of the script' except: print ('Could not find file' + path_input). But it doesn't seem to work. I've tried to move the try and except command after path_input, but that doesn't work either. I still get file '()' does not exist and the script stops.

Comment: Also, I apologize for all the questions, why do you have .lower() for the txt files? From my understanding all that does is transform the input all into lowercase?

Comment: You should put the try/except statements around the part where it tries to load the file, so when it iterates over the one that doesn't exist it will only handle the exception at that point, so put it around the for loop: `for csv_file in csv_file_paths:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep='\s+', header=None)
    data_frames.append(df)` loop. I'm going to edit the answer because I'm not sure how the formatting will go in the comment. The .lower() is just in case the user writes "Done" or "Quit" to get the proper match, just force of habit to sanitize user input as much as possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204627/discussion-between-joules-and-samman).